# Get size of Stage before it has been shown

Tags: java, javafx

I'm able to get size of any Node before it has been shown using:

```
parentNode.applyCss();
parentNode.layout();
```

but is there any way to get a Stage/Window size?

**My goal**: Setting Stage min size that depends on some node inside the Scene. I'm partially successful, but the problem is I have to include size of the title bar of my window (aka Stage), but it seems to be no way to get the title bar size before a window has been shown. If I knew the Stage size I can just simply do:

```
stage.getHeight() - stage.getScene().getHeight()
```

**Reproducible example:**

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        URL fxml = getClass().getResource("sample.fxml");
        HBox base = FXMLLoader.load(fxml);
        Scene scene = new Scene(base);

        base.applyCss();
        base.layout();

        VBox panel = (VBox) base.getChildren().get(0); //for example purposes,
        // I normally use custom classes, so I can easily access panel without those weird tricks

        primaryStage.setMinWidth(panel.getWidth());
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(panel.getHeight());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<HBox prefWidth="800" prefHeight="400" fillHeight="false" xmlns:fx="main">
    <VBox fx:id="panel" minWidth="150" style="-fx-background-color: gray;" >
        <Label text="Some text"/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
    </VBox>
    <HBox>
        <ImageView/>
    </HBox>
</HBox>
```

I want to have a Stage's minWidth and minHeight the same as panel's (VBox) width and height, so with minimal window's size my panel will be fully visible.

As you can see in my example Stage's minHeight doesn't match with panel's, because I need to add title bar's height, but I'm unable to calculate it before the Stage is shown

Comment: [`Window#sizeToScene()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#sizeToScene()) may be what you're looking for. But I don't know if it works before the stage is showing.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Sounds like a x-y-problem .. most of the time it's wrong to any of the min/max/pref sizes. Anyway, you need to provide a [mcve] to explain what you are after and how it doesn't work as you want it to

Comment: @kleopatra Just provided a simple one, I hope it's enough